# Cannot figure out how to pass data to expo route, query params preserved

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, navigation

I have a list of search hits on a `/search` route. Each search hit contains a link like so

```
<Link href={`/recipe?recipe=${JSON.stringify(recipe)}`} />
```

When I navigate to `/recipe`, everything is fine, the query params are all there. Everything breaks when I tap `back`. After going back to `/search`, if I tap again on a search hit, the page crashes with `malformed URIcomponent`. Some of the search hits have "%" or parenthesis in their name, causing this URI encoding error.
But when I try the obvious solutions, it still happens!

`const encodedName = encodeURIComponent(name);`

````
<Pressable
              onPress={() =>
                router.push(
                  `/recipe?id=${id}&name=${encodedName}&brandName=${brandName}&macros=${JSON.stringify(
                    macros
                  )}`
                )
              }
            >
    ```
````

Answer (score -1):

Look at the snippet from [exo docs](https://docs.expo.dev)

```
import { Link } from 'expo-router';


export default function Page() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: "/user/[id]",
          params: { id: 'bacon' }
        }}>
          View user
        </Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The directory structure is important here. The above example uses the directory structure below. Also note that `[id].js` filename.
[image]

[Here](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/navigating-pages/) is the URL for the mentioned code.

Comment: I changed it to 
```
<Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/recipe",
                params: { id, name, brandName, macros },
              }}
```
and it still doesn't work. `URIError: Malformed decodeURI input` when I tap on a different search hit after going back

Comment: Seems like you are doing something wrong here. Can you share the updated snippet

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem! It's not about the query params being preserved, it's about the uri encoding – some of the search hits I'm tapping on have parenthesis or % in them, leading to this URI encoding error. The problem is, the obvious solutions are not working. Updating my question